# Windows 7 Localhost not working properly with XAMPP

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, localhost

Hey there I'm running XAMPP on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit and I'm having some issues with my localhost setup, and i've been trawling the internet for ages trying to get this fixed but to no avail.

My setup is as follows:

I've got apache and mysql running on XAMPP no problem, and I've edited my hosts file no problem, ensuring i've used admin privileges in note pad etc and that its not saved as a .txt file etc. It currently looks like this:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handle within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 legendary-games.localhost
127.0.0.1 admin.legendary-games.localhost
127.0.0.1 shuuro.legendary-games.localhost
127.0.0.1 yearzero.legendary-games.localhost
127.0.0.1 chess.legendary-games.localhost
```

I've also made sure to make all the necessary changes to my vhosts file in apache and its all pointing to the correct address.

Now when I type localhost into my browser I get the page I'm meant to, however if I try any of the of the other addresses I get a page not found. I've tried pinging the addresses in the commandprompt and that comes back successful. I've tried many different things to try and get this working including flushing the dns, rebooting the dns, I've checked that the hosts file is being looked up properly by the services but to no avail.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: For clarification, when you type localhost, you get your page display from htdocs? But when you type an address not from local hosted for example google.com you get the response page not found? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes when I type localhost into a browser I get my file from htdocs, but when I one of the addresses from hosts file e.g. legendary-games.localhost this gives a page not found. Normal internet URLS work fine

Comment: I see. Have you enable vhost module on your apache? If you have enable then have you added an alias legendary-games.localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the solution maybe this helps you.

Add this line or uncomment from file httpd.conf found on your apache folder -> conf

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Edit httpd-vhosts.conf found on your apache folder -> conf -> extra

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "your-htdocs-path/legendary-games-folder"
    ServerName legendary-games.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, restart apache.

Comment: I've already uncommented the include vhosts in the apache conf file, and i've already added the following entry to my vhosts file:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/fisk/codebase/trunk/htdocs"
    ServerName legendary-games.localhost

    <Directory "C:/Users/fisk/codebase/trunk/htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny

        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>